# Regex match everything from the last occurrence of key to another key

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this text:

> OLD >> AAAAAA AA-BB dssd sdg Ad sdg ds Adsd gs AAA sdg dsg GGGGGG GG sdgds AAAA GF-S sdg . sdg. - 4353 ds gsd sdg GDS GDG 343 33 sdgsg sdgs DGSAGG DSDG S DG

new text

> AAAAAA AA-BB dssd sdg Ad sdg ds Adsd gs AAA sdg dsg GGGGGG GG sdgds AAAA GF-S sdg . Asdg. AA sdg dsg - 4353 ds gsd sdg GDS GDG 343 33 sdgsg sdgs DGSAGG DSDG S DG
>   And I want to extract the last occurrence of an uppercase string like `([A-Z -]+){5,100}` before a number:  `4353`

So in this case the results should be:

> AAAA GF-S

I tried `/([A-Z -.]+){5,100} (.+) 4353/i` but it gets me the first.

Thanks for the fast answers, I made a modification in the search text. 
It should be last expresion that has only upper cases and it length bigger than 5

Comment: note that `[space][dash][dot]` in your regex is going to be "from space to dot". If you're trying to match literal dashes, you'd need `[A-Z \-.]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Updated***

Try this:

```
.*(\b[A-Z][A-Z -.]{5,100})(?=.*4353)\K
```

**[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/fA6jE2/6)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
([A-Z][A-Z .-]{5,100})(?= [a-z .-]*4353)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iF2bM4/2)